# Android: Send a simple request with Volley not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I think this is a stupid question, but I really do not know what went wrong with my simple app (I am a Android newbie btw).

Even this "easy" example is not working for me (thats frustrating!)

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

I always get the message "That didn't work!".

My code is.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://www.apple.com"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)

    }

}
```

I develop with Android Studio and a Virtual Device on a Mac Book.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see the logcat..check for internet permission in manifest

Comment: Please edit the error listener so that you can know exactly what the error is.
You may log the error or do it like this:-   

 Response.ErrorListener {
                        error ->textView.text =error.toString()
                    })

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is OK so maybe your app is missing Internet permissions, which is of course mandatory for HTTP requests.

Please add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. In my manifest I already gave that permission. First I was a bit confused that the permission was not listed in the app info after it was installed on the device. But a short internet search later I found out, that those permissions are minor and therefore not listed in that view - long answer short - unfortunately this is not the problem here :-/

Answer (score 0):

I know it is VERY late but I think, I encountered the same issue until I tried an HTTPS instead of HTTP.